# How to create a conditonal JSON using python?

Tags: python, json

How do you construct a json in a loop where i need to add only conditional data like for example:

```
        {
         "Country" : [
           {
             "america": {
               "population": "23234234",
               "GDP": "12",
               "measureInVolume": "gallons"
             },
             "argentina": {
               "population": "14234",
               "GDP": "08",
               "measureInVolume": "litres"
             }
           }
          ]
        }
```

Now, how do i add an another dictionary value of "crime rate" to country "america" based on the conditional check whether the country is "america" in python?

I am trying in the following fashion to create it, but unable to succeed.

```
            import json

            data = {}
            data['Country'] = []
            counter = 1
            for cnt in range(0, 50):
                data['Country'].append({
                    "<<dynamic Country name from a different function>>": {
                        "population": "23234234",
                        "GDP": "12",
                        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
                    },

                })
                counter = counter + 1
            with open('countryList_gen.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Requesting help to over come this issue. Because as soon as i enter a if condition the python compiler on pycharm starts to show errors.

Thanks 
Shahid

Comment: just saying.. you don’t need `counter` because `cnt` is already doing that for you. Just do `range(1,51)`. Also please show us what the `if` statement you’re using maybe it’s something going wrong just when you implement that. Also the error you get would be helpful as well.

Comment: @jaba: The following is a sample code snippet for the if condition, if introduce in the middle of the loop, it breaks.
    if <<result from function >> == 'america':
        "crimeRate":"98"

Comment: Because you’re most likely using the if statement inside your dict initialization. Create the dict then use your if statement and then `.update()` the crimeRate see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm) for what I mean by updating it

Comment: @Jaba Thank you i was able to correct my mistake by using your advice.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question right, for me it looks a bit like you dont need to create a list out of country:

if you start like this:

```
data = {"Country": {}}
counter = 1

for cnt in range(0, 10):
    new_dic_name = "test" + str(counter) 
    data['Country'].update({new_dic_name : {
    "population": "data",
    "GDP": "data",
    "measureInVolume": "gallons"
     }})
     counter = counter + 1
```

would give you the following data output:

```
{
"Country": {
    "test1": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test2": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test3": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test4": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test5": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test6": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    }
}
}
```

then you could do the following:

```
for cnt in data["Country"]
if cnt == "test2": #you could implement your if clause here
    print("check")
    data['Country'][cnt]["population"] = "update"
    data['Country'][cnt]["GDP"] = "update"
    data['Country'][cnt]["measureInVolume"] = "update"
```

to get the following result:

```
{
"Country": {
    "test1": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test2": {
        "population": "update",
        "GDP": "update",
        "measureInVolume": "update"
    },
    "test3": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test4": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test5": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    },
    "test6": {
        "population": "data",
        "GDP": "data",
        "measureInVolume": "gallons"
    }
}
```

}

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Flow, thank you for your suggestion, but i see here 2 loops we execute to achieve it , which we are trying to avoid. However, i have got the solution, based on -Jaba suggestion. So thank you once again for your help :)

Thanks
Shahid